# Using PPA for on older version

Tags: ppa, version

If I were, for example, to be on 12.04, but there were PPA's that did not have Precise releases, could I change the PPA entry to use Oneiric rather than Precise? Would that cause problems?

If my question is unclear (It probably is), feel free to ask me for more information.

Comment: At first i thought you could do this with apt pinning but on reflection i dont think thats right.

Comment: What is apt pinning? Also, do you think it would be wise to maybe test this on, say, a package that does little, such as a custom indicator?

Comment: http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may work in some cases ,but in most of the cases it will causes broken dependencies,If you installed synaptic you can see red colour on such(broken) packages